#   HQL equivalent to this Sql Query

Tags: hibernate, hql

```
select part.PaId,part.PaName,part.PaPartNumber,part.PaGroup from Part as part,(select 
PaId,PaGroup from Part where PaPartNumber='195-15-12750') as pa where pa.PaId=part.PaID  
or pa.PaGroup=part.PaGroup
```

what is hql query for the above ?

replace all my names with classes and properties name,but error occurs!

**HQL:**

```
Select part.ID,part.Name,part.PartNumber From Part as part,(Select par.ID,par.Group 
From Part as par Where par.PartNumber Like ?) as pa Where part.ID=pa.ID or  
part.Group=pa.Group
```

**Error:**

```
SEVERE: line 1:73: unexpected token: (
Oct 26, 2011 7:23:01 PM org.hibernate.hql.ast.ErrorCounter reportError
SEVERE: line 1:98: unexpected token: From
unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 73 [Select part.ID,part.Name,part.PartNumber 
From Depot.Entity.Part as part,(Select par.ID,par.Group From Depot.Entity.Part as par 
Where par.PartNumber Like ?) as pa Where part.ID=pa.ID or part.Group=pa.Group]
[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@1195c2b
```

Comment: Without mappings how can we know the name?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to **replace your column names with the java property names and the table name with the java class name** and the HQL is ready then.